# Representing @EmbeddedId as SQL for H2 database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, h2

I am currently working on a Java project with [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) entities (more below). In order to test my data access object layers, I am using [H2 database](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) to populate an in-memory database and throwing queries at it. Until this point, everything is fine.

However, the problem comes when simulating the @EmbeddedId annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BSCOBJ")
public class BasicObject extends AbstractDomainObject {

    @EmbeddedId // This annotation here
    private RestrainPK restrain;

@Embeddable
public static class RestrainPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
    @Column(name = "CODI", nullable = false)
    private String  coDi;

    @Column(name = "COGA", nullable = false)
    private String  coGa;

    @Column(name = "TYOR", nullable = false)
    private String  tyOr;

    public RestrainPK() {
    }

    ... // Getters and setters

    }
}
```

"Simply" creating the table `BSCOBJ` and populating it gives no value when fetching data (of course, I checked that the request would give result "normally"). How do I represent this nested class in a SQL table creation / value insertion request ? Is that even possible ?

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT**

As requested, here is some samples about the SQL / Hibernate ran.

Creation request:

```
CREATE TABLE BSCOBJ (CODI VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, COGA VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, TYOR VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL);
```

Insertion request:

```
INSERT INTO BSCOBJ (CODI, COGA, TYOR) VALUES
('HELLO', 'MAT', 'REF'),
('BONJ', 'SOME', 'DAIL'),
('SOPA', 'KDA', 'RATIO');
```

Request given by Hibernate when trying to run the test code:

```
select r.restrain.tyOr from mypackage.BasicObject r where r.restrain.coDi = :coDi and r.restrain.coGa = :coGa
```

With the following values:

```
coDi = "BONJ";
coGa = "SOME";
```

Throws a `NoResultException`. I am expecting `DAIL`, from the second line of the `INSERT` request.

Comment: try to add a piece of code.. insertion  / query that does not work for you

Comment: ok try to also add the query creation using the session object.. so session.createQuery.. etc

Comment: Where is `TYOR` column in your query? all PK fields should be included in a select query, btw, instead of posting hibnertae query with data, try to post the test code that you run! ,

Comment: The goal is to retrieve `TYOR` from the table using `CODI` and `COGA`. I will post this code asap (time not really on my side on this one)

Answer (score 0):

I have used `@EmbeddedId` only one time, but I think that you need `@AttributeOverrides` under your `@EmbeddedId`

```
@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "idpk", column = @Column(name="IDPK", nullable = false),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "code", column = @Column(name="CODE")
})
```

and remove your `@Column` annotations from FormulePK